# Invoking function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have got,

```
var MyNameSpace.ShoppingList = {
    addItem: function (itemName, functionName, listName) {
        $("<li>", { text: itemName })
             .on("click", functionName)
             .appendTo($("#" + listName));
    },
};
```

then in another module,

```
var MyNameSpace.ModuleX = {
    init: function () {
         MyNameSpace.ShoppingList.addItem("Get Eggs From Market", alert("Run Me when listItemClicked"), "shoppingpoplist");
    },
};
```

**Question**

I want `alert("Run Me when listItemClicked")` to run only when listitem is clicked...

I already know changing it to this helps,

```
MyNameSpace.ShoppingList.addItem("Get Eggs From Market", function () { alert("Run Me when listItemClicked"); }, "shoppingpoplist");
```

But above solution makes my code very long, so there's no point for me adding a separate `addListItem`, can I solve above issue with least number of code ? Do I must need to add function () {}...  either where alert is called or in the addListItem method itself

If it's common practice to do so, then am I on right track of putting addItem in a separate method here ?

Comment: Your second option, with the surrounding `function() {...}` is a pretty standard practise - it's generally known as a _callback_.

Comment: You might be able to shorten it to `alert.bind(window, "Run Me when listItemClicked")`, but I'm not sure that is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ES6, you get arrow functions, which shorten things considerably:

```
MyNameSpace.ShoppingList.addItem("Get Eggs From Market",
    () => alert("Run Me when listItemClicked"), "shoppingpoplist");
//  ^^^^^ equivalent to function() { return ... }
```

If you can't use arrow functions (which are supported in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, but not IE11 and below), you can do something like this if you really want:

```
function handleWithAlert(msg) {
    return function() { alert(msg); };
}
```

```
MyNameSpace.ShoppingList.addItem("Get Eggs From Market", 
    handleWithAlert("Run Me when listItemClicked"), "shoppingpoplist");
```

`handleWithAlert()` will return a function, which is what's expected to be passed as the first parameter. So you get a generic event handler generator for alert messages.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `alert(..)` will call alert immediately and pass its return value into `addItem`. What you need instead is to pass a function that *when called* will execute `alert(..)`. There are pretty much three options for this:

```
function () { alert(..); }
```

or:

```
alert.bind(null, '..')
```

or:

```
function callback() {
    alert(..);
}
addItem(.., callback)
```

Take your pick. It doesn't get any shorter.